# El código PHP no surte efectos en una página HTML

Tags: php, html

He hecho el siguiente script PHP:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <?php
      echo "<form action='ejercicio5.php' method='post'>
        Elije un color de fondo:
        <select name='colordefondo'>
        <option value='black'>Negro</option>
        <option value='white'>Blanco</option>
        <option value='blue'>Azul</option>
        <option value='yellow'>Amarillo</option>
        <option value='red'>Rojo</option>
        <option value='green'>Verde</option>
        </select><br />

        Elije el color del texto:
        <select name='colordetexto'>
        <option value='black'>Negro</option>
        <option value='white'>Blanco</option>
        <option value='blue'>Azul</option>
        <option value='yellow'>Amarillo</option>
        <option value='red'>Rojo</option>
        <option value='green'>Verde</option>
        </select><br />

        Elije el tamaño del texto a mostrar (en px): <input type='text' name='tamañotexto' value=''><br />
        Escribe el texto a mostrar: <input type='text' name='texto' value='Hola'>

        <input type='submit' value='Mostrar texto''></form>";

        $colordetexto=$_POST['$colordetexto'];
        $tamañotexto=$_POST['$tamañotexto'];
        $colordefondo=$_POST['$colordefondo'];
        $texto=$_POST['$texto'];
    ?>

    <style>
    p.estilo {
      color: <?php echo $colordetexto; ?>;
      font-size:<?php echo $tamañotexto; ?>px;
    }
    body {
      background-color:<?php echo $colordefondo; ?>;
    }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p class='estilo'><?php echo $texto; ?></p>
  </body>
</html>
```

El enunciado del problema dice:

> Cuando se pulse sobre el botón “mostrar texto” deberá aparecer el texto (escrito en el cuadro de texto correspondiente) con el tamaño y color especificados, sobre el color de fondo seleccionado.

El problema es que todo está bien definido, pero es como si no guardase las variables.

¿Por qué sucede esto? Cuando le doy al botón no hace nada.

Comment: Veo que tienes la variable $texto alojando un arreglo $_POST , El post se usa para recibir data a través de HTTP. Si quieres imprimir solo guarda la cadena en la varibale texto . Si quieres recibir un dato de post necesito confirmar los detalles del petición HTTP

Comment: No lo he entendido muy bien... Se refiere a que use $GET? No sé lo que son los detalles del petición HTTP...

Comment: Pregunta , el propósito de tu código es recibir un texto por parte de un formulario que luego usa dato recibido para imprimir la misma pantalla con el texto recibido ?

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a la comunidad. Te invito a hacer el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y leer [¿cómo escribo una buena respuesta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) para que tu respuesta sea bien recibida por parte de la comunidad. Si lo que quieres es preguntar más detalles deberías hacerlo en forma de comentario. Si aún no tienes reputación suficiente para hacerlo te invito a participar en la comunidad para conseguirla.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes una errata en el nombre de los campos POST que estás recibiendo. En el nombre de la clave estás agregando un signo dólar innecesario:

```
$colordetexto=$_POST['$colordetexto'];
$tamañotexto=$_POST['$tamañotexto'];
$colordefondo=$_POST['$colordefondo'];
$texto=$_POST['$texto'];
```

Debería ser:

```
$colordetexto = $_POST['colordetexto'];
$tamañotexto = $_POST['tamañotexto'];
$colordefondo = $_POST['colordefondo'];
$texto = $_POST['texto'];
```

Además, te sugiero:

- No uses variables transitorias en el código (una variable que contiene el valor de otra variable). En vez de usar `$texto` usa siempre `$_POST['texto']`, así sabrás en todo momento el origen del contenido.
- Separa el código HTML del PHP tanto como puedas: no envíes el código HTML de un formulario a través de un `echo` de tamaño enorme. Es difícil de mantener y depurar.
- Usa [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars) para enviar texto fuera de tu control al navegador. Evitarás que se rompa el diseño de tu página en el mejor de los casos, o que ésta sufra problemas de seguridad ([XSS](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting)) en el peor de ellos.
- Procura no introducir etiquetas de `<body>` dentro del `<head>`. Tu navegador mostrará la página bien, pero deberías evitar generar un HTML incorrecto.

---

Siguiendo mis recomendaciones tu código podría quedar como muestro a continuación:

```php
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <style>
      p.estilo {
        color: <?= htmlspecialchars($_POST['colordetexto']) ?>;
        font-size: <?= htmlspecialchars($_POST['tamañotexto']) ?>px;
      }
      body {
        background-color: <?= htmlspecialchars($_POST['colordefondo']) ?>;
      }
    </style>
  <head>
  <body>
    <form action='ejercicio5.php' method='post'>
      Elije un color de fondo:
      <select name='colordefondo'>
        <option value='black'>Negro</option>
        <option value='white'>Blanco</option>
        <option value='blue'>Azul</option>
        <option value='yellow'>Amarillo</option>
        <option value='red'>Rojo</option>
        <option value='green'>Verde</option>
      </select>
      <br />

      Elije el color del texto:
      <select name='colordetexto'>
        <option value='black'>Negro</option>
        <option value='white'>Blanco</option>
        <option value='blue'>Azul</option>
        <option value='yellow'>Amarillo</option>
        <option value='red'>Rojo</option>
        <option value='green'>Verde</option>
      </select>
      <br />

      Elije el tamaño del texto a mostrar (en px):
      <input type='text' name='tamañotexto' value=''>
      <br />
      Escribe el texto a mostrar:
      <input type='text' name='texto' value='Hola'>

      <input type='submit' value='Mostrar texto''>
    </form>
    <h2>Aquí se mostrará tu texto:</h2>
    <p class='estilo'><?= htmlspecialchars($_POST['texto']) ?></p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Como ejercicio final, podrías mantener la selección anterior entre envíos del formulario y, además, impedir que se puedan enviar opciones que no están contempladas en los `<select>` (es la medida de seguridad básica de cualquier formulario).

Gracias al `htmlspecialchars()` impido que se pueda salir del ámbito de la etiqueta `<style>` para inyectar HTML usando el código CSS generado, pero eso no evita que éste genere un error de sintaxis, quede corrupto o, peor aún, puedan modificarlo de manera maliciosa o incluir CSS externos.